# Do, Write Through

Tags: data-format, writing

Using:

```
Do[Write[OUTFILE, #] & @@ Through[{(#) &, Sin[#] &, Cos[#] &}[n]], {n, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]
```

results with file content:

```
{1, Sin[1], Cos[1]}
{2, Sin[2], Cos[2]}
{3, Sin[3], Cos[3]}
{4, Sin[4], Cos[4]}
```

But I would like to have:

```
1,Sin[1],Cos[1]
2,Sin[2],Cos[2]
3,Sin[3],Cos[3]
4,Sin[4],Cos[4]
```

And, additionally, when writing file paths, they are quoted.
How to write path stripped of quotes?

Comment: Something like `ExportString[RandomReal[1, {3, 4}], "CSV"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *want* to write one line at a time, use `ExportString` on each line, then `WriteString`:

```
 Do[
     WriteString[OUTFILE,
       ExportString[{ Through[{(#) &, Sin[#] &, Cos[#] &}[n]] }, "CSV"] <> "\n"],
            {n, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]
```

Generally you should save up the output data and `Export` it all at once though.
Only write in the loop like that if for example the loop time is very long and you need the output always up to date.