# Huge CSV file with numeric and text data

Tags: performance-tuning, import, csv-format

I try to load a huge CSV file (~ 4 Gbyte), the data is both numeric and textual.
So, I can't load the data as a string.

```
str = OpenRead["train.csv"];
data = ReadList[str, String];
```

When I try to `Import` the file directly, my notebook is crash (  Win 10, WL 11.3, and my PC has 32G of RAM). The link to the data:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/microsoft-malware-prediction/data
To deal with this issue, I split the original file to a few parts and load each one and save in ".mx" format. Any suggestion on how to load the file in a more efficient way

Comment: `Import` is known to be somewhat memory inefficient. For simple text formats like CSV you could try to read in chunks. That will be especially efficient when you only need parts of the data (specific rows or columns). You will find several Q/A on this site which show examples how to do that...

Comment: Here are some links: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65756/efficiently-reading-csv-with-readlist?rq=1
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35371/speeding-up-import-and-export-in-csv-format?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recognize this when larger files and/or depending on fileformats. A brute force solution is to increase the size for the java virtual machine, for example

```
`<< JLink`;InstallJava[];
ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx6144m"];`
```

Comment: Thank a lot, I will try this.

Comment: Since you have 32GB, you  can of course increase the number after "-Xm"

Comment: Have you actually tried that for CSV files? While there are several formats which are imported via java, I am not sure but think that importing CSV does not even use java, so changing the java stack size might not help in this case...

Comment: Good point. Is there any documentation on what Import uses for different formats? If import of CSV doesn't use Java then increasing the memory will not help. My own experience is that Import is a great function but a bit too "black boxy" and seems to be undergoing changes. E.g. I have programs that worked with 10.x that stopped working with 11.3 due to Unicode issues.